# Question about Websocket protocol

Tags: protocol-theory, transport-protocol

In order to establish a Websocket connection, according to the WebSocket protocol, the client must send to the server a HTTP Upgrade Request. This is the client's handshake. 
Now, please tell me if I'm wrong: is it true that before sending that message the client must establish a TCP connection with the server, and that the client can only send that message after the TCP's three-way handshake?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Websocket uses TCP as its protocol, then yes, you must establish a TCP connection before passing any other traffic.

This is the same as any other protocol that utilizes TCP, such as HTTP, FTP, SSH, etc.

Once the TCP connection is established, then the request to establish the Websocket connection can be sent across that TCP connection.  In practical use, the TCP connection will already be established if the Websocket request is going to the same host that was part of an earlier HTTP request, assuming the TCP connection hasn't been closed yet.